# React Native WebView after Upgrade latest showing white screen

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

In my react native project i'm using react-native-webview 13.8.1 it's working properly .But when i upgrade to 13.8.1 build success but after that showing white blank screen. Why?

React-native version -  0.71.6,
react-native-webview": ^11.26.0.